# WPF databinding: view not updating from viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

My WPF app is working in a strange way for me - some binding works, other not.

I have following situation:

A textbox - user provides an ID. Based on this ID an object is loaded or created. Some other properties are updated by values coming from the loaded/new object.

Binding for the ID textbox works fine. However, two other views (any other) not.

My code samples:
XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="ID" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" />
            <TextBox x:Name="TB_PacientID" Width="100px" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=PacientID}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="TBL_NovyPacient" Text="nový pacient" Margin="5,0,0,0" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsNewPacient,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Converter={StaticResource BTVConverter}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
<WrapPanel x:Name="WP_PacientData" Margin="-2,5,2,5" Visibility="{Binding PacientLoaded,Converter={StaticResource BTVConverter}}">
 ...
```

Viewmodel:

```
public int? PacientID
{
    get
    {
        if (CurrentPacient == null)
            return null;
        return CurrentPacient.id;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            _pacient = App.instance.sessionData.serviceProxy.pacientById(value.Value);
            if (_pacient == null)
            {
                CurrentPacient = new Pacient() { id = value.Value };
                IsNewPacient = true;
            }
            else
            {
                CurrentPacient = _pacient;
            }                                                            
            OnPropertyChanged();
            PacientLoaded = true;
        }
    }
}

// ...

public bool IsNewPacient
{
    get{ return _isNewPacient; }
    set
    {
        _isNewPacient = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

//...

public bool PacientLoaded
{
    get{ return _pacientLoaded; }
    set
    {
        _pacientLoaded = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

The idea:
User inputs the ID, an object is loaded or created and the WrapPanel is shown. If the object is newly created the TextBlock is shown as well.
The converters are working fine (tested in another window).

When the window loads, the binding is established well (if I set some fake values in ctor). When changing the ID in textbox, nothing other updates - except for the ID itself - the setter is fired well and the new value is read after OnPropertyChanged is called.

I hope I'm missing something very easy and stupid.

-Edit:
Current state:
TB_PacientID is working (updading), TBL_NovyPacient and WP_PacientData not working (updating).
I want:
All thee views updating from viewmodel (the code properties).

-Edit 2
I created a very simple example of my problem from scratch:
A window - two textboxes:

```
<Window x:Class="bindingTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="TestTextBox" Text="{Binding ID, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="SecondTextBox" Text="{Binding IsNew, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Codebehind:

```
 namespace bindingTest
 {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new TestViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

And the viewmodel class:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 namespace bindingTest
 {
    public abstract class ViewModelBase
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }        
    }

    public class TestViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private bool _attOne;
        private int? id;        

        private bool _isNew;

        public bool IsNew
        {
            get
            {
                return _isNew;
            }
            set
            {
                _isNew = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public int? ID
        {
            get
            {
                return id;
            }
            set
            {
                this.id = value;
                IsNew = true;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And what I simply want - If I change the number in the first textbox I want to have True in the second textbox automatically.

Comment: You have to be a little bit more clear. What are you expecting to get updated and isn't getting updated? Which binding  isn't working? That is information we need to know.

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's not possible to say for sure what might be wrong with your code.

Comment: PD, TYY - thank you for responding, I've just provided a very simple example with identical problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I am stupid.

My ViewModel base class lost the INotifyPropertyChanged interface while merging from another project.
So I called the OnPropertyChanged, but it has been my own OnPropertyChanged instead of implementation of the interface which is WPF binding waiting for.

Answer (score 0):

I had threethings to point in your code sample:

1. You should use a TwoWay binding for setting the ID.
2. Are you sure the `_pacient = App.instance.sessionData.serviceProxy.pacientById(value.Value);` code returns always the same object instance.
3. Are you correctly using the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in most cases you raising a property change events looks like this: `RaisePropertyChanged('PropertyName');` you are invoking: 'OnPropertyChanged();'

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you for responding!
1. it does not help (just tried it now) - I think the two way binding is default
2. yep, I'm quite sure (behind this is hidden a factory with caching)
3. my viewmodel is inherited from my general viewmodel that uses .NET 4.5 feature:
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
which inserts me the caller property name as an argument to the OnPropertyChanged correctly (checked)